# Changing iPad volume not affecting App

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, volume

I have a universal game app i'm making and when I turn the volume up and down on the iPad it has no affect on app. The app's volume is always the same no matter how much I change the volume on iPad. This issue only occurs on iPad, no issue on iPhones. I use AudioToolbox framework if it matters.

Why is the app volume not affected when I change it on iPad? What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably changed the device volume, but there is also app volume (at the settings).
(In order to be sure that this is the problem, test the volume at other apps...)

Comment: You're correct, I didn't even realize that in settings --> Sound --> RINGER AND ALERTS, that you can click and unclick "Change With Buttons" volume. It was unclicked, that's why the volume wasn't working when I was changing it on iPad. When I clicked it then everything started to work normally.